# Suggestions on get_text() in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse some content from a html page.

I can extract from the html the content I want (i.e. the text contained in a `span` defined by the `class` myclass).

```
result = mycontent.find(attrs={'class':'myclass'})
```

I obtain this result:

```
<span class="myclass">Lorem ipsum<br/>dolor sit amet,<br/>consectetur...</span>
```

If I try to extract the text using:

```
result.get_text()
```

I obtain:

```
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet,consectetur...
```

As you can see when the tag `<br>` is removed there is no more spacing between the contents and two words are concated.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Use 'contents' , then replace <br>?

Comment: can you put this into an example so that i can accept the answer? thanks

Comment: On iPhone right now. Need to get near a computer to create tested code. I hope someone else will create example for you in the meantime.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using bs4 you can use [`strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
" ".join(result.strings)
```

Comment: Or use the kwarg separator, that does the same thing inside get_text:

result.get_text('separator='" ") -> 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...'

Answer (score 19):

Use 'contents' , then replace `<br>`?

Here is a full (working, tested) example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://www.floris.us/SO/bstest.html"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

result = soup.find(attrs={'class':'myclass'})
print "The result of soup.find:"
print result

print "\nresult.contents:"
print result.contents
print "\nresult.get_text():"
print result.get_text()
for r in result:
  if (r.string is None):
    r.string = ' '

print "\nAfter replacing all the 'None' with ' ':"
print result.get_text()
```

Result:

```
The result of soup.find:
<span class="myclass">Lorem ipsum<br/>dolor sit amet,<br/>consectetur...</span>

result.contents:
[u'Lorem ipsum', <br/>, u'dolor sit amet,', <br/>, u'consectetur...']

result.get_text():
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet,consectetur...

After replacing all the 'None' with ' ':
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...
```

This is more elaborate than Sean's very compact solution - but since I had said I would create and test a solution along the lines I had indicate when I could, I decided to follow through on my promise. You can see a little better what is going on here - the `<br/>` is its own element in the `result.contents` tuple, but when converted to string there's "nothing left".

Answer (score 6):

`result.get_text(separator=" ")` should work.

Comment: How is that not the most upvoted answer? That literally solved all of my problems in a freaking line