# beautiful soup just get the value inside the tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The following command:

```
volume = soup.findAll("span", {"id": "volume"})[0]
```

gives:

```
<span class="gr_text1" id="volume">16,103.3</span>
```

when I issue a print(volume).

How do I get just the number?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Extract the string from the element:

```
volume = soup.findAll("span", {"id": "volume"})[0].string
```

Answer (score 14):

Using [css selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> soup.select('span#volume')[0].text
u'16,103.3'
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
for a in volume:
    a.get_text()
```

[recent response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318980/using-beatifulsoup-get-text)

[managing exceptions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121001/suggestions-on-get-text-in-beautifulsoup)

[managing exceptions 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255709/python-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get-text)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add , I also found the `.string` dosn't do well when there is `<br>` in the text.

EG:

```
 <div class = "Lines">
    <span> First Line <br> Second Line <br> Third Line </span>
  </div>
```

If we do a `soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"Lines}).span.string` we get a `None`

But a `soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"Lines}).span.text` we get

> ```
> First Line
> Second Line
> Third Line
> ```

I think the `.string` gives a `NavigatableString` object and `.text` gives a unicode object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for getting the value of the tag : tag.contents[0]

Try this :

```
volumes = soup('span')
for volume in volumes:
     print(volume.contents[0])
```