# Using beautifulsoup get_text()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can parse the field that I need from a website with this code block:

```
response = requests.get(index_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
poem = soup.select('div.siir p[id^=siir]')
print poem
```

But it prints with HTML tags. I'm trying to use `get_text()` function. When I try to use like this:

```
print poem.get_text()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I also tried to use like this:

```
poem = soup.select('div.siir p[id^=siir]').get_text()
```

I get same error again. How can I eliminate the HTML tags after I parse the correct field?

Comment: If you are using the latest `BeautifulSoup` and you need a single element matching a selector, there is also `select_one()`: `poem = soup.select_one('div.siir p[id^=siir]')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`soup.select()` always returns a *list* of elements, not just one element. Call `get_text()` on each element in turn:

```
for element in poem:
    print element.get_text()
```

If you expected just one element, then extract it with indexing:

```
print poem[0].get_text()
```