# beautiful soup get value inside a tag / class

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Referred to [beautiful soup just get the value inside the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003302/beautiful-soup-just-get-the-value-inside-the-tag/44065476#44065476), I've tried to transfer this code to my HTML tag (see below) but unfortunately, I couldn´t find a solution yet. This is my HTML example:

```
<div id="city" class="temperature">29</div>
```

I want to scrape the temperature value (= 29). Any hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> soup
<div id="city" class="temperature">29</div>
>>> soup.div
<div id="city" class="temperature">29</div>
>>> soup.div.text
u'29'
```

Comment: Easier than expected... Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

[I tried responding to your query with my python 3.6.x ipython terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sswWa.png)

Comment: Please add code demonstrating your solution to your answer.

Comment: Just click on  the link it will display an image which would be the code demonstration for the question asked.

Comment: Add code here instead of in an image on another site. So people with the same problem can visit here and read the solution easily