# Python - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am following some tutorial for bs4. I am trying to get_text() for below example with 'a'. Tutorial return result McDermott International and MDR without problem. But when I do I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'. Please help. Many thanks!

```
with open('Energy.htm') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f,"lxml")
energylist = soup.find_all('td', {"style" : "text-align:left;"})
for stock in energylist:
    try:
        stock_name = stock.find('a').get_text()
    except:
        stock_name = ''

#sample of the energylist
[<td style="text-align:left;">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:MDR&amp;ei=nblKWaDrOs7AmgH0l7S4Bg">McDermott 
International</a>
</td>, <td style="text-align:left;">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:MDR&amp;ei=nblKWaDrOs7AmgH0l7S4Bg">MDR</a>
</td>, <td style="text-align:left;">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:EQT&amp;ei=nblKWaDrOs7AmgH0l7S4Bg">EQT</a>
</td>, <td colspan="8" style="text-align:left;">
Companies <b>1 - 20</b> of about <b>476</b> in <b>Energy</b> 
</td>]
```

Comment: It means it has not found the `a` tag. Can you show how you've processed the source into the `energylist`?

Comment: Thank you Willem, I was using Google Finance for this project. Sample page is like this:
https://www.google.com/finance?catid=TRBC%3A50&ei=erHdV6HdFcKgeJXHlrgO

After I parse it with beautiful soup. I tried to narrow down my data to the topmover of the market. I edit the code in the original post to include how to get the energylist. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

It would seem `energylist` has some tags that do not contain the anchor tag within them. You'll need to add a condition to handle those gracefully:

```
for stock in energylist:
    try:
        stock_name = stock.find('a').get_text()
        ... # more code
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: I put in the try for the get_text and except to return blank. The error has gone but I still extract the stock name from there. Seems there the problem is to search the data with <a but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @David Sorry, I don't understand what is the problem. Are you printing out your data?