# How to get only the text information from a string type data using python's BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the data as in str format in python as shown.

```
data
 '  </h3>\n</div>\n<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element " data-wow-delay="0.3s">\n<div class="wpb_wrapper">\n<p>\xa0</p>\n<h4><span style="font-weight: 400;">Our Backbone\xa0</span></h4>\n<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">We use various techniques of AI like Neural \n\n'
```

I want to take the text in this data. If it was in tag(< >) and not in string format , i can use the `.string()` or `get_text()` for the `bs4.element.ResultSet` type. Here it could not be used since it is string type. How to get the whole string data from it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beautiful soup just get the value inside the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003302/beautiful-soup-just-get-the-value-inside-the-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call `getText()` on the entire document

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
text=soup.getText().replace("\n","")
#  Our Backbone We use various techniques of AI like Neural
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract from specific tags, you can try something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(data,'html.parser')
a = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'wpb_wrapper'})]
```