# Python getting the part after div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is what I have

```
<div class="investor-item" usrid="75500">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="number">10,000€</div>
<div class="date">03 December 2018</div>
</div>
```

I would like to scrape "75500", but have no clue how to do that.
When I use

```
soup.findAll('div',{"class":"investor-item"})
```

it does not capture what I want. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beautiful soup just get the value inside the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003302/beautiful-soup-just-get-the-value-inside-the-tag)

Comment: Try this `soup.find(class_="investor-item")["usrid"]`.

Comment: But I don't know "75500" in my case whereas in your example ="volume" is same across all data. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SIM, this is what I want, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could capture this. Your command worked for me.  Though since you have a Euro sign in there, you may want to make sure your script is using the right encoding.  Also, remember that `find_all` will return a list, not just the first matching item.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="investor-item" usrid="75500">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="number">10,000€</div>
<div class="date">03 December 2018</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
mytag = soup.find('div', {"class": "investor-item"})
mytag2 = soup.find('div', class_="investor-item")
mytag3 = soup.find_all('div', class_="investor-item")[0]
mytag4 = soup.findAll('div', class_="investor-item")[0]
mytag5 = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"investor-item"})[0]

print(mytag['usrid'])  # Returns 75500
print(mytag2['usrid'])  # Also returns 75500
print(mytag3['usrid'])  # Also returns 75500
print(mytag4['usrid'])  # Also returns 75500
print(mytag5['usrid'])  # Also returns 75500
```

**EDIT**: Here are some more details on the 5 different examples I gave.

- The typical naming convention for Python functions is to use all lowercase and underscores, whereas some other languages use camel case. So although although `find_all()` is more of the "official" way to do this in BeautifulSoup with Python, and `findAll` is something you'd see in BeautifulSoup for other languages, Python seems to accept it too.
- As mentioned, `find_all` returns a list whereas `find` returns the
  first match, so doing a `find_all` and taking the first element
  (`[0]`) gives the same result.
- Finally, `{"class": "investor-item"}` is an example of the general way you can specify attributes beyond just the HTML tag name itself.  You just pass in the additional parameters in a dictionary like this.  But since `class` is such a common attribute to look for in a tag, BeautifulSoup gives you the option of not having to use a dictionary and instead typing `class_=` followed by a string of the class name you're looking for. The reason for that underscore is so that Python doesn't confuse it with `class`, the Python command to create a *Python* class in your code.

Comment: Bill M.: can you please explain what - conceptually - are the differences between your 5 "mytag"s?