# How can get just time in this parsing method

Tags: python, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

[image]My code is like this:

```
for row in tables.find_all('tr'):
    time = row.select_one('td.first.left.time')
    print(time)
```

and output likethis:

```
> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text
> editor None None <td class="first left time">18:10</td> None <td
> class="first left time">19:50</td> None <td class="first left
> time">20:01</td> None <td class="first left time">21:15</td> None None
> <td class="first left time">03:00</td> None <td class="first left
> time">03:00</td> None <td class="first left time">06:00</td>
```

How can get just number?

Comment: `row.select_one(...).text`?

Comment: I tried but it gives:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 2
      1 for row in tables.find_all('tr'):
----> 2     time = row.select_one('td.first.left.time').text
      3     print(time)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Yep, then there's some row that doesn't have a `time` cell and you'll need to add an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

With BeautifulSoup, you might want to use `time = row.select_one('td.first.left.time').string` to get the text value. (See [beautiful soup just get the value inside the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003302/beautiful-soup-just-get-the-value-inside-the-tag)).

Comment: Thank you for reaching! But no it's not working here the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: Problem here that it's not a str or int. It's object that contain time, so where i need to look to
 get that time and convert to str?