# how to get partial text from a long tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have been studying a shopping website, and I want to extract the brandname and the product name from its html code like the following:

`<h1 class="product-name elim-suites">Chantecaille<span itemprop="name" >Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette</span></h1>`

I tried: `results = soup.findAll("h1", {"class" : "product-name elim-suites"})[0].text`

and got: `u'ChantecailleLimited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette'`

As you can see, Chantecaille is the brandname, the rest is the product name, but they are now sticked to each other, any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: try using `.contents` or `.strings` instead of `.text` and then joining the strings as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121001/suggestions-on-get-text-in-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`previous_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling), which gets the previous node that has the same parent (same level in the parse tree).

Also, instead of `findAll`, when you are searching for a single element, use `find`.

```
item_span = soup.find("h1", {"class" : "product-name elim-suites"}).find("span")

product_name = item_span.previous_sibling
brand_name = item_span.text

print product_name
print brand_name
```

Output:

```
Chantecaille
Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *get_text* and pass a character to separate the text or pull the text using `. h1.find(text=True, recursive=False)` on the `h1` and pull the text from the *span* directly:

```
In [1]: h ="""<h1 class="product-name elim-suites">Chantecaille<span itemprop="name" >Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette
   ...: </span></h1>"""

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")

In [4]: h1 = soup.select_one("h1.product-name.elim-suites")

In [5]: print(h1.get_text("\n"))
Chantecaille
Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette


In [6]: prod, desc = h1.find(text=True, recursive=False), h1.span.text

In [7]: print(prod, desc)
(u'Chantecaille', u'Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette\n')
```

Or if text could appear after the *span* also use *find_all*:

```
In [8]: h ="""<h1 class="product-name elim-suites">Chantecaille
<span itemprop="name" >Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette</span>other text</h1>"""


In [9]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [10]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")

In [11]: h1 = soup.select_one("h1.product-name.elim-suites")

In [12]: print(h1.get_text("\n"))
Chantecaille
Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette
other text

In [13]: prod, desc = " ".join(h1.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)), h1.span.text

In [14]: 

In [14]: print(prod, desc)
(u'Chantecaille other text', u'Limited Edition Protect the Lion Eye Palette')
```